# How to restart the wireless with a changed configuration on command line?

Tags: wireless, command-line, network-manager

I have a wireless device under the name `wlan0` in Ubuntu 13.10. I want to change the configuration of a network to be found in the following directory

```
/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections
```

I would like to do the following:

1. Stop the wireless connection
2. Change the configuration of a network in the mentioned path
3. Restart the connection

How to do that? I tried `ifdown`, but this command tells me that `wlan0` is not configured, and I tried `nmcli c up/down`, but this command does not seem to 'reread' the changed configuration?

So how to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

You must use:

```
nmcli nm wifi on/off
```

no `nmcli c up/down`.

Answer (score 0):

The commands ifdown/ifup just manage interfaces in /etc/network/interfaces. These are explicitly not managed by the NetworkManager.

So static interfaces (which could be static or dynamically assigned IPv4 and IPv6 addresses) I usually manage there instead of by the NetworkManager. Most often it's servers, as I don't use use graphical interfaces on servers.
NM is in my opinion most usefully on laptops and not on stationary computers, but your mileage might be different.